# Controller variables aren't reaching my view

Tags: grails, gsp

The variables defined in my controller aren't reaching my view.

For instance: `http://localhost:8080/assetScopes/edit/4`

I'm not seeing any errors in the console nor am I seeing the output of the variables in the view.

I am seeing the expected output in the console from the `println` statements however.

Controller - `grails-app/controllers/com/aps/cmdb/AssetScopesController.groovy`:

```
....
def edit(AssetScopes assetScopes) {
    def scopes = assetScopes as JSON
    println(scopes)
    def myvar = "testing"
    println(myvar)

    [scopes:scopes, myvar:myvar, assetScopes:assetScopes]
}
....
```

View - `grails-app/views/assetScopes/edit.gsp`:

```
<%= scopes %>
<%= assetScopes %>
<%= myvar %>

${scopes}
${assetScopes}
${myvar}
```

Configuration: Windows 7 Pro, Cygwin, SDK Man, Grails 3.0.9, MySQL 5.6

**Update #1**

I thought it wouldn't matter, but maybe it does. Instead of GORM Domains, I reused Hibernate configuration files and Domains. The `generate-all` CLI command was used to generate the controller and the views.

So far, the `edit` and `create` actions are exhibiting the behavior listed in my OP. However, the other views are fine (ie. `show` and `index`).

Comment: You don't need the scriptlet tags at the top of the page. You can just access the values directly.

Comment: @christopher Agreed. I just wanted to try every concievable way to output content in my view :)